# Asynchronous function not working Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want the users status should be OFFLINE once he logout from the app. Sp i wrote the following statements in the logout menu --

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_lout) {
        status = "Offline";
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("MyApp")
                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        session.logoutUser();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
    }
```

Now the problem is Alert Box is showing and user is also logged out. But his status is still ONLINE in the database.

```
status = "Offline";
    mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
    mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
```

This part is not executing. Pls help.

Code for UserLoginTask Class--

```
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    UserLoginTask() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        InputStream is = null;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", uEmailID));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", status));

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com/Android/checkIsOnline.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            is = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString().trim();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your `UserLoginTask` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call this AsyncTask inside alert dialog onclick, change execute() to .executeOnExecutor(). Then check your onpreexecute and doInBackground working or not.

Comment: changing change execute() to .executeOnExecutor() -- where?

Comment: mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
        mAuthTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

Comment: Have you logged first line inside doinBackground? First of all you should check whether your doinbackground is working or not. Then httpclient is deprecated, i prefer httpurlconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an asynchronous task you need to wait for the response of the task in order to show the AlertDialog.

My opinion: Move alert dialog inside UserLoginTask() after you have a HTTP 200 OK response from logout process.

Comment: I tried ur suggestion, but not worked. same issue, status not changed

Answer (score 0):

Call this method on positive button clicked inside the dialog..Also remove this code "(Void) null" as byDefault Void itself is passed inside asyntask.

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("MyApp")
            .setMessage("Are you sure?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    session.logoutUser();
                    status = "Offline";
                    mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
                    mAuthTask.execute();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
```